# Единый таможенный союз

Tags: орфография

В этом словосочетании только первое слово пишется с прописной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, конечно только первое. И то только если речь идёт о конкретной организации с таким названием. Для заглавных в остальных случаях просто нет причин.
~~~~
Добавлено (по результатам обсуждения).
Ныне существующий союз России, Беларуси и Казахстана носит название "Таможенный союз", слово "единый" в него не входит, поэтому написание, если такое встретится, будет: единый Таможенный союз.

Answer (score 0):

А про что именно идет речь? Если речь идет про Таможенный союз (в который входят Белоруссия и Россия), то "единый" может запросто быть определением...

Comment: Вряд ли бы его назвали "единым". Хотя теоретически - да, в этом случае "Таможенный", конечно, с заглавной, "единый" - со строчной.  
Но, насколько понимаю, ЕТС - это возможное последующее развитие союза России, Белорусии и Казахстана (с 2011-го) на страны ЕврАзЭС.

Comment: Мне просто понравилась Ваша безапелляционность в ответе...

Comment: Конкретный вопрос требует конкретного ответа. 
В принципе я люблю "порассуждать", но в данном случае, надеюсь, я правильно понял спрашивающего.  
В любом случае - спасибо, я дополнил ответ.